# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I am trying to find a (smooth, if possible) homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$. i have come with some ideas, but the resulting functions are somewhat complicated. Is there a "simple-equation" homeomorphism between these two spaces ?

Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions !!!

Greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work inside $\mathbb{C}$ and think of $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}_{+}$ as the quadrant with positive real and imaginary parts, and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{+}$ as the upper-half complex plane. The map $z \to z^2$ sends the former to the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, $\mathbb{R}_+$ does includes the zero element of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think it still works.

Comment: so $\mathbb{R}_{+}=[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, precisely !!

Answer (score 3):

$(r,\theta)\mapsto (r^2,2\theta)$ will work!, or $(x,y)\mapsto ( x^2+y^2, 2\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x})$

Comment: Perhaps you meant $(x,y)\mapsto(x,\log y)$?

Comment: I saw no problem with the map $(x,y)\mapsto(x,\log y)$, why to change it ?

Comment: $\log 0$ is not defined

Comment: The second option is not defined at (0,0), is it ?